# NSString won't survive segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, segue

I have two view controllers with a segue between them. I'm calling the segue via code and I want to pass an NSString between the two view controllers. Looks like Xcode reaches the line where I set the value for the NSString in the second view controller, but when the actual controller loads it shows 0x0000000 instead of the actual data.

This is how I call the second view controller

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueuIdentifier" sender:reader];
```

This is how I set the value on the second view controller (there is only one segue):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    [secondViewController setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/test.html?t=%@", testValue]];
}
```

I'm sure the testValue has value (I made sure in debug mode).

On the second view controller this is what I have in the h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *UrlAddress;
```

And I made sure I `@synthesize` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the property strong:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *UrlAddress;
```

Comment: Worked great - thank you. But I have a different project that does exactly the same thing with weak instead of strong and it works... How weird...